# Retrieving output from a url. How do I force the dowload of a PDF from a url using php

Tags: php, url, header, file-get-contents, ob-get-contents

I need to retrieve our reports from the jasperserver report engine as a PDF, then I want the PDF to be forced as a download, instead of being displayed inthe browser.  The problem with displaying in the browser is we don't want the report parameters to be displayed to the end users in the url.

If I enter this URL path into the browser I get a PDF document that shows in the same browser window with all the report data:

```
https://mysite.com:8443/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=sample_report&output=pdf;
```

What I would prefer to have happen is for a download dialog box to be used and for the users to download the PDF to their computer, instead of it showing in the browser.

I've tried the following php code, but can't get it to work.  I get a return value of false, but nothing in the server logs that shows an error.

```
ob_start();
    header("Location: $src"); /* Redirect browser */
    $report_contents = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    var_dump($report_contents);
```

I'm not really sure how to go about this...anyone got any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could buffer the file to the PHP server then output with force download:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=huge_document.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile('https://mysite.com:8443/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=sample_report&output=pdf;');
```

See the notes about using `readfile` over an HTTP stream wrapper
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Thanks for the code.  I tried putting your suggestion in but I get an error:  [Wed Feb 15 15:06:37 2012] [error] [client 209.33.199.176] PHP Warning:  readfile() [<a href='function.readfile'>function.readfile</a>]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message     and I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
$source=$url
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Pragma: cache");

header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
readfile($source);
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  WHen I added the code above I got the following error:  PHP Warning:  readfile() [<a href='function.readfile'>function.readfile</a>]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message

Comment: may need to switch to curl over readfile() it has better support for ssl.

Comment: thanks, got the curl to output stuff, but can't get it to download a pdf document...if I retrieve the report as html then I can echo out the html, but the pdf report does nothing.  any ideas?